# Find holidays between two dates in php

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime, foreach

Hi I have 3 dates `DropoffDate, atd and utd`.
Logic is
`atd = DropOffDate + 3 Days` and `utd = DropOffDate + 9 Days`

if `DropOffDate = 24-12-2019` then `atd = 27-12-2019 and utd = 02-01-2020`

And I have an array of holidays

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25-12-2019
    [1] => 01-01-2020
    [2] => 18-04-2019
    [3] => 26-12-2019
    [4] => 01-08-2021
    [5] => 30-11-2021
    [6] => 04-01-2021
)
```

Now the requirement is to find out all the holidays between DropOffDate and atd and add that many days to atd and same for utd. If the final atd or utd falls on holiday again, add one more day to it.

So far I have written this script but it only fetches the first holiday and doesn't looks for next holidays

```
$holidayList = Array
(
    [0] => 25-12-2019
    [1] => 01-01-2020
    [2] => 18-04-2019
    [3] => 26-12-2019
    [4] => 01-08-2021
    [5] => 30-11-2021
    [6] => 04-01-2021
)
            
            $dropDate = '24-12-2019';
            $atd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+3 days", $dod));
            $utd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+9 days", $dod));
            $dropDate = strtotime($dropDate);
            $atd = strtotime($atd);
            $utd = strtotime($utd);

            foreach($holidayList as $holiday){
                $holiDate = date('d-m-Y' , strtotime($holiday));
                $holiDate = strtotime($holiDate);

                if (($holiDate >= $dropDate) && ($holiDate <= $atd)){
                    $atd = date('d-m-Y' , $atd);
                    $atd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+1 days", $atd));
                }
                if(($holiDate >= $dropDate) && ($holiDate <= $utd)){
                    $utd = date('d-m-Y' , $utd);
                    $utd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+1 days", $utd));
                }
            } 

            echo "<b>AT Date".$atd."<br>";
            echo "<b>UT Date".$utd;
```

The ATD and UTD's should be 29-12-2019 and 5-1-2020. please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code has unnecessary date conversions from timestamp to string. If you clear everything you get the expected dates.

```
$dropDate = strtotime('24-12-2019');
$atd = strtotime("+3 days", $dropDate);
$utd = strtotime("+9 days", $dropDate);

foreach($holidayList as $holiday){
    $holiDate = strtotime($holiday);

    if (($holiDate >= $dropDate) && ($holiDate <= $atd)){
        $atd = strtotime("+1 days", $atd);
    }
    if(($holiDate >= $dropDate) && ($holiDate <= $utd)){
        $utd = strtotime("+1 days", $utd);
    }
} 

echo "AT Date ",  date('d-m-Y',$atd), "\n";
echo "UT Date ",  date('d-m-Y',$utd);

// Output:
// AT Date 29-12-2019
// UT Date 05-01-2020
```

[fiddle](https://3v4l.org/Fg16c)